# Rails computation on large table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, rails-activerecord, tf-idf

I'll try to explain my problem.
I've created a table which represents something like text model for the user(**user_models**) based on purchases. I have also a table **term_tfs** which stores user_id and term(varchar(200)) as PK plus some other numeric columns. It is basically a matrix with terms and their numeric tf_idf_norm values for model. Now I need to make a computation comparing user models, so I need to load this matrix for one user and compare it with others for different users.

The problem is, that term_tfs table is really big (cca. 13.5 mill. rows) and I need to get matrices for users with at least 5 (1285 users) or 10 (9333) purchases. When I make one select from term_tfs table it takes 20-40 millis approximately. But I need some way how to do this for other 9-thousands users to compare with. Naive approach which makes query for each user_id into term_tfs takes something above 10 s for one comparison, which is slow if I want to do this comparison for next few thousand users and store it somewhere else.

```
def self.compare_user(user_id)
  @results = Hash.new
  # @user_ids = UserModel.where.not(user_id: user_id).pluck(:user_id)
  @user_ids = UserModel.get_useful_ids(user_id, 5)
  @user_matrix = TermTf.where(user_id: user_id).pluck(:term,  :tf_idf_norm)
  @user_terms = @user_matrix.map { |a| a[0] }


  @user_ids.each do |id|

    matrix = TermTf.where(user_id: id).pluck(:term, :tf_idf_norm)
    store_result( compare_matrix(matrix), id )

  end

  sort_results( @results )
end

def self.compare_matrix(matrix)
  sim = 0

  matrix.each do |t|
    unless ( ( i = @user_terms.index(t[0]) ).nil? )
      sim += t[1] * @user_matrix[i][1]
    end
  end

  sim
end

def self.store_result(similarity, id)
  @results[id] = similarity
end
```

Benchmark output (9333 user_ids):

```
puts Benchmark.measure {@user_ids.each{|id| TermTf.where(user_id:  id).pluck(:term, :tf_idf_norm)}}
4.890000   0.180000   5.070000 ( 11.019708)
```

This seems as rather bad/slow approach, so how to make it faster? I'm all pro to hear other ways how to solve this problem too, with Ruby or SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To put Beartech's approach into Rails code instead of creating a view, you can do some thing like this (needs to be adjusted to your needs):

```
subquery = TermTf.where(user_id: user_id).select(:term,  :tf_idf_norm).to_sql
result = TermTf.joins("INNER JOIN (#{subquery }) sub on sub.term = term_tfs.term")
         .select("term_tfs.user_id as user_id, sum(sub.tf_idf_norm * term_tfs.tf_idf_norm) as tf_idf_norm_sum")
         .where(user_id: @user_ids)
         .where.not(user_id:  user_id)
         .group('term_tfs.user_id')
         .all
```

Comment: Ok, thanks. Looks interesting. So if I'm correct you try to join my query with the whole term_tfs_table on the same terms and then group by other users ids and make a sum of all their equal terms. This line:                 .where("photos.user_id != ?", user_id) I do not get since I've not said anything about photo column. I'll try it.

Comment: `.where("photos.user_id != ?", user_id)` might be "better" (or at least more Railsy) as `.where.not(photos: { user_id: user_id })`.

Comment: @user2229608 I did correct my answer. `photos` was a typo I did mean table `term_tfs`. It should prevent that entries for the current user id are taken into account for the sum.

Comment: @mu is too short You are right. `where.not` is more RoR like. Bad Rails 3 habit.

Comment: it's much faster ;)

Comment: But I do not need Active::record at all, if I get just the user_ids from objects, it basically bogges down to the same time

Answer (score 1):

My answer would be to not do it in Rails. You say at the end that you would like to know how to do it in Ruby, but I hope you will consider a non-ruby answer. If it is slow in Rails it's because Rails is not "good" at that particular process. I had several large tables that I had to display in my app. If you watch the Rails console and it shows lots of DB requests or slow performance you should move that process to the DB. The dB designers have been tuning the DB to handle those processes for years.

I would recreate the same logic in SQL and add it as a view in your DB. You can then add a simple model like:

In your models

term_tfs_view.rb

```
class TermTfsView  < ActiveRecord::Base
   #this is a model for a view in the DB
end
```

In your DB name your table `term_tfs_views` and it will automatically associate this model with the table.

My SQL skills are rudimentary, else I would try and give you an example of your logic translated from Ruby/Rails to SQL. If a SQL expert can weigh in and let us know if this is practical to do using SQL it would help.

**Important**

Views are great for data that you want to view. You can't do updates/inserts/etc. Using a view backed model. But that does not mean they are not great for moving heavy lifting from Rails to the DB. This link explains the idea of View backed Models very well: https://dan.chak.org/enterprise-rails/chapter-11-view-backed-models/

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes, SQL solution is OK too, but since I'm not that great DB expert I'd need to see some example how to do that.  You suggest using views, so I'll look into your article.